# How to modify the form of an object?

Tags: modeling

I am modeling a new skin for Vel'koz League of Legends, but I can't figure out how to modify a form.

I want to make this form converging to an empty or to the cursor. Should look likes a cone.

I would get this mesh

[image: mesh one]

Converging on this empty

[image: empty one]

Comment: too hard to understand what you want, please show some screenshots

Comment: Ok I will. Thanks

Comment: you could try with the Proportional Editing option, or maybe you would have a better result with a modifier like the Mesh Deform modifier: Create a cage around your mesh and stretch + scale it

Comment: I am sorry because i am brand new to blender so I don't really unserstand how to do these options. Can you explain please?

Comment: or you can try to use curve modifier

Comment: I already tried that modifiers but couldn't make the form i wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with the Proportional Editing option on, but you should have a better result with the *Mesh Deform* modifier:

- Create a cube that encompass your object.
- Subdivide it a bit.
- In the *Properties* panel > *Data* > *Display*, choose *Maximum Draw Type* > *Wire* so that it's transparent in *Object* mode. To make it transparent in *Render* mode, go in the *Properties* panel > *Data* > *Cycles Settings* and disable all.
- Give your mesh a *Mesh Deform* modifier with the cube as *Object*. Click on the *Bind* button.
- Move or scale the edges of your cube to modify the shape of your object.
- When you're happy, apply the modifier (maybe keep a unapplied copy somewhere though).

[image]

Comment: @SherlockLaTruite Don't post "Thank you" as a comment, instead upvote the answer. If it solved your problem consider marking it as accepted.

Comment: How to make my post solved?

Comment: on the top left of my answer there should be a check icon, just tick it